# apache security - detecting and blocking probing IP addresses

Tags: apache, security, unix, cpanel, configserver

Looking through my apache error logs in `/var/log/apache2/error_log` I am seeing a ton of IPs trying access files that don't exist.  I interpret these as bots probing my web server trying to find a vulnerability file to exploit

Files like:

```
/var/www/html/compress.php
/var/www/html/index.php
/var/www/html/wp-login.php
/var/www/hmtl/getcfg.php
```

I then go to look at the `/var/www/` directory and do find the `/cgi-bin` and the `/html` subfolders in them.  The /cgi-bin folder is empty, but the /html folder has a handful of files like: `400.shtml, 401.shtml, 403.shtml, 404.shtml` and even `index.html`.  I then read that these are apache created and owned - is this true?  If so...what is the purpose of this folder/files?

Is there any apache...or ConfigServer (firewall) configuration that I can use that can detect these probing IPs and auto-block them?  Any IP that keeps looking for multiple files that don't exist - implying its not a user (or even a bot) that is properly access the correct HTML pages - is malicious and should be blocked.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about CSF, but there is an Apache module, mod_evasive that will help. With some tweaks, it will do anything you want.

https://blog.cpanel.com/blocking-attacks-with-easyapache-4s-mod_evasive/
https://docs.cpanel.net/ea4/apache/apache-module-evasive/